# Returning entries within specified month

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a spreadsheet with many rows. In column "S" are 3digit codes and in column "T" dates in dd/mm/yyyy format. I want to create a macro which will search for all rows with specified code (which is written in cell "S1") within the specified month (month/year is written in cell "T1")and copies the whole rows for which these 2 conditions are true into the new sheet. So in example below the row 5 should be copied into new sheet.

| Row | Column S | Column T |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **306** | **02/2022** |
| 2 | 223 | 01/01/2022 |
| 3 | 306 | 03/01/2022 |
| 4 | 456 | 02/02/2022 |
| 5 | 306 | 03/02/2022 |
| 5 | 231 | 02/02/2022 |

With some help I have managed to write the VBA code- it is doing the right thing if it comes to searching for the rows with the code from cell S1 but if it comes to the dates it returns all entries from the beginning of the year to the end of the month specified in cell T1 and not only from this month. Do you know how I should correct this code so it gives only the entries from one month?

```
Function IsDateInMonth _
  (d As Date, m As Date) As Boolean


Dim dStart As Date
Dim dEnd As Date

dStart = CDate(VBA.Month(m) & "/01/" & VBA.Year(m))
dEnd = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(m, 0)

If d >= dStart And d <= dEnd Then IsDateInMonth = True

End Function

Sub Macro()

Dim strCode As String
Dim datDate As Date
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLoop As Long
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim wksTarget As Worksheet

Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TABLE")
Set wksTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

lngLoop = 2

strCode = Range("S1")
datDate = Range("T1")

For Each rngCell In wksSource.Range("S4:S30000")

  If rngCell = strCode _
  And IsDateInMonth(rngCell.Offset(, 1), datDate) Then

    wksSource.Rows(rngCell.Row).Copy wksTarget.Rows(lngLoop)
    lngLoop = lngLoop + 1

  End If

Next rngCell

End Sub
```

I want only the rows whith code specified in cell $S$1 and from the month specified in cell $T$1

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub FindAndCopy()
    Dim searchValue, firstAddress
    Dim oRng As Range, fRng As Range
    Dim lngLoop As Long: lngLoop = 2
    Dim wksTarget As Worksheet
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    
    Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TABLE")
    Set oRng = wksSource.Range("S4:S30000")
    searchValue = wksSource.Range("S1")
    Set wksTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Set fRng = oRng.Find(What:=searchValue, _
                              After:=oRng.Cells(oRng.Cells.Count), _
                              LookIn:=xlValues, _
                              LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                              MatchCase:=False)
        If Not fRng Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = fRng.Address
            Do
                 If fRng = searchValue _
                 And Month(fRng.Offset(0, 1)) = Month(wksSource.Range("T1")) _
                 And Year(fRng.Offset(0, 1)) = Year(wksSource.Range("T1")) Then
                    wksSource.Rows(fRng.Row).Copy wksTarget.Rows(lngLoop)
                    lngLoop = lngLoop + 1
                  End If
                  Set fRng = oRng.FindNext(fRng)
             Loop While Not fRng Is Nothing And fRng.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
        Msgbox "Copy complete"
End Sub
```